# How do I assign numeric values to the alphabet in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to convert a character string to a numeric variable and then sum the values of each character to use as a unique identifier for that field.
So for example, I would like A=1, B=2, C=3.....X=24  Y=25  Z=26.
Say my string is "CAB" so after running the code I would like the result to be an intermidiary column of numbers, where the value for CAB IS   3 1 2  and the result column would be derived by summing the string 3+1+2= 6  and show the value of the intermideate column, so the final value woud be 6.

Here is the sas code I used to convert the characters to numbers, but I need help with the result column.

```
DATA CHAR_VALUE;
SET WORK.XYZ;
CHAR_2_NUM=TRANSLATE(MY_VAR_CHAR, '1 2 3 ...24 25 26', 'A B C ...X Y Z');
NUM_CHAR=INPUT(CHAR_2_NUM,32.);
RUN;
```

Thanks in advance...I appreciate any help or suggestions.
-rachel

Answer (score 2):

RANK will give the ASCII numeric value underlying a character; so A=65, B=66, Z=90, a=97, z=122.

So this should work (if you want only the uppercase values - not a different value for a than A):

```
data test;
charval='CAB';
do _t=1 to length(Charval);
    numval=sum(numval,rank(char(upcase(charval),_t))-64);
end;
put _all_;
run;
```

Another option (Based on the comments below), is to build an informat with the relationships between letter and value.  My loop iterates over each character A to Z, you can then put whatever value you want for each letter as label (I just put 1,2,3,4... but label= will change that).

```
data fmts;
retain fmtname 'CHARNUM' type 'i';
do _t=65 to 90;
start=byte(_t); *the character, so byte(65)='A';
label=_t-64;    *the resulting number;
output;
end;
run;
proc format cntlin=fmts;
quit;

data test;
charval='CAB';
do _t=1 to length(Charval);
    numval=sum(numval,input(char(upcase(charval),_t),CHARNUM.));
end;
put _all_;
run;
```

Finally, if you want to be able to construct this in the *same* datastep, you could construct the relationships in a hash table and look up the result.  I can explain that if desired, though I'd like to see a more detailed example of what you want to do in terms of defining the relationship between a letter and its code.

If you need to see the intermediate values, you can do that by inserting a CAT function in the loop- I recommend CATX:

```
data test;
charval='CAB';
format intermed $100.;
   do _t=1 to length(Charval);
        numval=sum(numval,input(char(upcase(charval),_t),CHARNUM.));
        intermed=catx('|',intermed,input(char(upcase(charval),_t),CHARNUM.)); *or the RANK portion from earlier;
    end;


put _all_;
run;
```

That would give you `3|1|2`, which you could then do math on via SCAN:

```
do _t = 1 to countc(intermed,'|')+1;
  numval2 = sum(numval2,scan(intermed,_t,'|'));
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically want to assign the values to the letters, as above, or I may want to modify the pattern, say like,

Comment: This   A=n(n-1)/2 ...So its important that A=1 and B=2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is based on the `collate` function:

To convert a variable called `MyNumbers` (in the range of 1 to 26) to English upper-case characters, one can use:

```
collate(64 + MyNumbers, 64 + MyNumbers)
```

To obtain lower-case characters, one can use:

```
collate(96 + MyNumbers, 96 + MyNumbers)
```

Here's a quick example:

```
data _null_;
    do MyNumbers = 1 to 26;
          MyLettersUpper = collate(64 + MyNumbers, 64 + MyNumbers);
          MyLettersLower = collate(96 + MyNumbers, 96 + MyNumbers);
          put MyNumbers MyLettersUpper MyLettersLower;
    end;
run;

    1 A a
    2 B b
    3 C c
    4 D d
    5 E e
    6 F f
    7 G g
    8 H h
    9 I i
    10 J j
    11 K k
    12 L l
    13 M m
    14 N n
    15 O o
    16 P p
    17 Q q
    18 R r
    19 S s
    20 T t
    21 U u
    22 V v
    23 W w
    24 X x
    25 Y y
    26 Z z
    NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
          real time           0.03 seconds
          cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method to try and translate is a good attempt, but it will not really work.  Here is a simple solution:

```
DATA CHAR_VALUE;
  retain all_chars 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMMOPQRSTUVXXYZ';
  set XYZ;

  length CHAR_2_NUM $200;
  CHAR_2_NUM = ' ';
  NUM_CHAR = 0;

  do i=1 to length(MY_VAR_CHAR);
     if i=1 then CHAR_2_NUM = substr(MY_VAR_CHAR,i,1);
            else CHAR_2_NUM = trim(CHAR_2_NUM) || ' ' || substr(MY_VAR_CHAR,i,1);
     NUM_CHAR + index(all_chars,substr(MY_VAR_CHAR,i,1));
     end;
  drop i all_chars;
RUN;
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the indexed position of each character of your source variable in the `all_chars` variable corresponds to the mapping you desired.

**UPDATED** to also create your `CHAR_2_NUM` variable, which I overlooked in the original question.

Comment: I'd recommend the CATX function instead of that complicated trim/|| stuff.

Comment: @Joe: I'd be happy to see an example of using CATX to build a new string with blanks between each character. `CHAR_2_NUM = catx(CHAR_2_NUM, ' ',  substr(MY_VAR_CHAR,i,1));` does not work.

Comment: See my solution above (in the 2nd to last block) :)  CATX takes its first argument as the separator, so CATX(' ',str1,str2,str3,...) would separate the various strings with spaces.

Comment: Joe,Youre awsome! The code works great. Thank you again...so much.

Comment: I am using this to turn millions of names into numbers to try and group them so if theres a letter thats missing or transposed the name's value will be relatively close to the original value. At least thats the beginning...my goal is identify similair names in a a table so that I'm not counting them more then once...my data is very raw. Thanks again, you're an excellent programmer, and your code is very helpful. Best, -rachel

Comment: Rachel, you should look into the SOUNDEX function, then (or similar - SAS has several).  Look it up in the docs. It performs basically the function you describe.

Comment: Joe, thanks for the suggestion, I will play with it over the weekend.

Comment: One more thing, I realized since I have millions of records, I can try and build a dictioanary or a list of sorts, using the names I have, then standardizing the name by the spelling by the most commonly occurring  in my list, so for example the list would decide if Jeffery or Geoffrey is output to the dictionary. Not sure yet...as I'm making this up as I'm mining the data. But I will definitely use your code to score the names. I'll test several  numerical combinations to assign to NUM_CHAR. You really made it easier for me. Thanks again!

Comment: Bob, thanks for the code above...incredibly helpful..btw..whats a good source for making maps in sas using lats, longs, zip codes, area codes. We don't have esri at work...so I'm trying to use sas. So far I've made a few basic choro maps, but nothing spectacular. I read an article online which gives decent instructions on making a choro map using Python. Theres a book called visualizing data, but not sure if it will be helpful, but the maps they show are impressive.

Comment: @user601828 I've found Robert Allison's website a great resource for all maps and charts in SAS.  Just find an example that's close to what you are trying to do then take his code and modify as needed.  Also you definitely want to look into the `soundex` function as Joe suggested.  It will do exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Rob Allison's site is:  http://robslink.com/SAS/Home.htm

Comment: Bob, thanks thats a great website. I will use the soundex function to compare results. How can I modify your code if I wanted to subtract the value of the vowels or value of the consonants from NUM_CHAR.

Comment: I want to preserve the order and value, so I'm guessing the modification needs to be within the function. I see that there's a pattern between vowels, and its 1,5,9,15,21 where the vowels correspond to those positions, so the the distance between the A and E is 4, then between E and I is also 4, then the last are 6 and 6.

Comment: I want to remove the value of the vowels from each name thus I will get more unique values. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: So for example, if MY_VAR_CHAR is "CAB" then the value of NUM_CHAR is

Comment: The value of NUM_CHAR is 1+2+3=6 but now I want to subtrac the value of the vowels, which in this case is A, and resulting value, of my vowel-less variable is NUM_CHAR-VOWEL_CHAR = 6-1=5

Comment: So my final variable's value is consonant_name=5